# Switch between accounts to run smart contracts

Tags: web3js, truffle, unittesting

I'm using `truffle develop` to test my smart contracts. I've tried to switch between different accounts using `web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[1]` but had no success. How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

As a style thing, I like to declare participants up front:

```
contract('MyContract', function(accounts) {

    var owner = accounts[0];
    var seller = accounts[1];
    var buyer = accounts[2];
```

Then, while running tests (or UI), explicitly spell out who is talking:

```
it("should do something", function() {
    myContract.method(args, {from: owner}).then(...
```

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

The `accounts` array is a list of accounts from the wallet (not the network, per se), so the test client is capable of signing using any of them.

Although truffle uses a "clean room" approach to tests, you can avoid reliance on it and avoid possible confusion by deploying a new, fresh contract before each test. This method ignores the migrations and contends with the network configuration on an "as is" basis. It affords you the opportunity to control the deployment process including which account deploys the contract at the client-side test level.

```
var myContract; // this will be the contract instance

beforeEach("deploy new MyContract", function() {
    return MyContract.new(args, { from: owner }) // make a new one and choose the deployer
        .then(instance => myContract = instance);
});
```

If you put it all together, you'll get something like

```
MyContract = artifacts.require(...

contract('MyContract', function(accounts) {

    var myContract;        
    var owner = accounts[0];
    var seller = accounts[1];
    var buyer = accounts[2];

    beforeEach("deploy new MyContract", function() {
      return MyContract.new(args, { from: owner }) // control who deployed it
      .then(instance => myContract = instance);
    });

    it("should do something", function() {
      myContract.method(args, {from: owner}).then(... // control who accesses it
```

Comment: Didn't know there was a way that smart contracts could access the networks's account addresses. That's pretty helpful.

But my problem is on the client side. Whenever I run `truffle develop`, it defaults to the first account. I don't think I can change that on `truffle-config.js` so I'm trying to switch the client's account on the console.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default account used by a contract from the 'develop' command line

```
> MetaCoin.defaults({ from: '0x123413413412341234' })
```

This will affect all transaction executed to that contract.

---

As indicated by Rob another options is to explicitly override `from` in each transaction.

```
> MetaCoin.deployed().transfer(to, value,
    { from: '0x13412341234...' })
```

---

It is possible to specify `from` in the configuration file `truffle-config.js`.

This is more complex but it is handy if something from `develop` doesn't suit your requirements.

You have to define your own network and run your own instance of ganache.

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    myCustomConfiguration: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*",
      from: '0x11111..111'
    }
  }
};
```

Now execute `ganache` in another console, and you can launch `truffle console --network myCustomConfiguration`.